# Get selected radio button id placed in navigation view

Tags: android, radio-group, drawerlayout, navigationview

I have taken radio group in the navigation view of drawer layout like this

```
 <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
     app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
     app:menu="@menu/drawer">

 <RadioGroup>
      <RadioButton/>
      <RadioButton/>
 </RadioGroup>

     </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

I want to get the selected radio button text or id but I am not getting any logs or Toast and no errors also..

Code for getting selected radio button:

```
rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
         @Override
         public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            int pos=rg.indexOfChild(findViewById(checkedId));
             Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ID = "+String.valueOf(pos),
                     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             Log.e("",""+pos);
         }
```

I know I can achieve this by using custom list view.. But how to get this working..

Comment: set a tag to a radio button then get the tag in the above code according to position,means radiobutton1.setTag(1) and radioButton2.setTag(2) in rg. setOnCheckedChangeListener just put if condition (radiobutton1.getTag==1){// do the stuff} else {//do another stuff};

Answer (score 0):

Sorry couldn't answer in comment. Try this:

```
navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.radioButtonId);
```

this will return Id of your `RadioButton`.

Edit:

Can you do something like this:

```
RadioButton radio = (RadioButton)navigationView.findViewById(R.id.radioButtonId);
```

Comment: Can you do something like this:

RadioButton radio = (RadioButton)navigationView.findViewById(R.id.radioButtonId);

Answer (score 0):

**Example - just like provided in developer.android**

*You just need to add attribute onClick in xml file like below*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_pirates"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/pirates"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_ninjas"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/ninjas"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
</RadioGroup>
```

*Handle the onClick event in code part*

```
 public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
    // Is the button now checked?
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

    // Check which radio button was clicked
    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.radio_pirates:
            if (checked)
                // Pirates are the best
            break;
        case R.id.radio_ninjas:
            if (checked)
                // Ninjas rule
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: But if I m writing Log or toast in **if(checked)** part I am not getting anything..